# Jackal Cannot Drive using PS4 Controller or Publishing ROS Message

Tags: jackal

I have tried to drive my Jackal both using a PS4 controller and through publishing a rostopic, both of which inputs are being sent successfully but with no response from Jackal.

I have successfully paired a Bluetooth controller and checked using jstest that the inputs are being correctly sent. Likewise, when trying to publish a topic to drive the motors directly using:

```
‘rostopic pub --once /jackal_velocity_controller/cmd_vel_unstamped geometry_msgs/msg/Twist '{linear: {x: 0.5, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}'
```

The message, ‘publishing and launching message for 3.0 seconds’, is displayed, but again no response from the motors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's a Jackal?

Comment: Clearpath Robotics has an off-the-shelf rover made for research called Jackal.

Comment: Should the command line have the single quote at the start and end or is that an artefact from trying to perform code formatting?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the output from `rosnode list` and `rostopic list`. Insert this as formatted text, not as a screenshot.